# HTML Forms: Submit button that goes to querystring?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, query-string

I'm working on a Rails site, and I've got my database indexed with IndexTank. I have things set up so that to search, all I have to do is browse to `[root]/search?q=[query]`. To simplify things, I'm planning on just dropping a `HTML` form with a textbox and a submit button in amongst the `erb`, but I'm not quite sure how to pass the information from the text box to the end of the `/search?q=` line.

I'm sure that this is terribly basic, but I've been Googling all morning and I've come up empty-handed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form action="/search">
    <label>Search term <input name="q"></label>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: So will the data on this form be submitted via POST, or GET?

Comment: *i* asked for nothing, but i thought it would be a good idea to clarify what's going on here, since kivetros doesn't know why this would work.

Comment: Yes, please do tell - it works great, but I'd really appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you'll probably need to post some more code. That said, the solution is likely as simple as setting your `form` element's `method` attribute to `GET`.